# Installing libgit2 and pygit2 in archlinux docker

Tags: python, docker, libgit2, pygit2

Trying to install libgit2 and pygit2 in docker. Keep running into errors no matter how I try.

```
Current docker file: https://pastebin.com/jsbdqeEX
Current error: https://pastebin.com/MVHXUuxa
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask for cmake issues.

Comment: Also if you can include errors (or at least the important parts if they are huge) in the question rather than on external sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in case you haven't figured it out yet that line says it all:

```
  /bin/sh: cmake: command not found
```

You just need

```
pacman --quiet --noconfirm -S cmake
```

Comment: It was this, I found it eventually. Thank you nonetheless.